# MySQL: "LIMIT 5" causes warnings

Tags: mysql, sql, warnings

I've been executing the following query in MySQL console:

```sql
INSERT INTO pixel_window 
   SELECT id 
      FROM pixels 
         WHERE pixel_id='type2' 
            ORDER BY id DESC 
               LIMIT 5;
```

And got:

```
Query OK, 5 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1592
Message: Statement may not be safe to log in statement format.
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've played a little with the query, and found out that when `LIMIT` is omitted the warning disappears.

What does this warning mean? Why is `LIMIT` a problem in this subquery?

Comment: I think this is related to the redo log of mysql, in case of crash they store everything you're doing... So logging it like this might confuse recovery (intuition)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's considered a bug.

A warning can be thrown when you don't define 'order by' clause in your update.
In your case, it is considered safe since you order by ID (asuming id is a unique id?)

Read more on the bugreport here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42415